# how replace Hashtag with Link in NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, next-link

**I tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML but still not working it only returns an [object Object]**

how to use Link to replace the hashtags in string

```
    import Link from 'next/link';
    
    export default function Home() {
      const text = '#sample this is link #stackoverflow';
    
      // Use regular expressions to match the hashtag
      const hashtag_regex = /#(\w+)/g;
      const hashtagMatch = text.match(hashtag_regex);
    
      // Replace the hashtag with a Link component
      let formatted_text = text;
      if (hashtagMatch) {
        hashtagMatch.forEach((match) => {
          formatted_text = formatted_text .replace(
            match,
            <Link href={`/hashtags/${match.slice(1)}`}>{match}</Link>
          );
        });
      }
    
      
      return <>{formatted_text}</>;
    }
```